# How to get real location (coordinates) of an object

Tags: coordinates

When I applying modifications like "Track To" or/and "Copy Rotation" to object, it location of the object on Numeric Panel (Transform) does not changes but the object really change location and it see in a Viewport.

Also I tried to got coordinates from Python but unsuccessful, they mirror values from Numeric Panel:

```py
bpy.data.objects["Camera"].location
bpy.data.objects["Camera"].rotation_euler
```

How I can to get real position and rotation of the object? How to get numeric location that it can to copy and to apply to another object?

Comment: `ob.matrix_world` contains the visual transforms in global coordinates.  eg  `loc, rot, scale = ob.matrix_world.decompose()`

Comment: Thank you! It does what I need